# root like privileges

Tags: linux

How do I create a new account (CentOS) and allow it root equivalent privileges?

I can add the user using the following command:

```
/usr/sbin/useradd test
```

I can change password using the following command:

```
passwd test
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [`sudo`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/sudo) for that. You can add the user to the `sudoers` file using `visudo`. Then the user can issue commands such as:

```
sudo some-command
```

which will allow them to have root privileges for the command.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the UID in /etc/passwd to 0. But do realize you are defeating the purpose of having a root(superuser) account by doing this.